# CSS transition doesn't work on DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, css, dom, css-transitions

Let's say I've got some block with `left` style property defined and with `transition` for that property:

```
<div id="caret" class="caret" style="left: 20px"></div>

.caret {
    transition: left 0.3s;
}
```

Okay, now when I change `left` via `$.css()` I've got everything transitioning perfectly:

```
$('#caret').css('left', '100px');
```

But when I move the block from one place to another in DOM and then change `left`, nothing transitioning, it just immediately jumps to the given value:

```
$('#caret').appendTo('#container').css('left', '50px');
```

Hovever, if I wait a bit and change `left` again, transition is back again. It feels like it needs some time to prepare.

I've created a simple showcase to demonstrate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/L624m/2/

So, why is that happening?

Comment: Waiting for the next [animation frame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) might fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your JavaScript code, in a typical browser, won't let the DOM create the new element first, so the style will actually be applied directly to the new element, causing no transition at all.

After appending the element you have to "interrupt" the JavaScript and let the DOM notice the new element first; usually this is done by using a `setTimeout` with 0ms interval, like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    caret.css('left', left === '20px' ? '100px' : '20px');
},0);
```

So, because of the `setTimeout`, the browser will always queue the change in the `left` style **after** the changes in DOM are really made instead of being queued themselves too.

Comment: Thought the same and tried it in his fiddle however it did not work on my machine. (FF)

Comment: Worked on Chrome, works on Firefox just from time to time. Seems that Chrome is just faster than FF.

Comment: Can this be remediated by setting the timeout a couple of milliseconds higher?